# Check if all string values of one array are either similar or sub-string of another array values

Tags: php, arrays

Ok posting this query after going through many similar issues but they took into consideration only numeric values. So my issue is:

I have 2 arrays -

```
$a = ["XYZ1250H100",
"XYZ1280H130",
"XYZ1250H150",
"XYZ3300H200",
"XYZ3350H200",
"XYZ33350H280Ada08",
"XYZ33450H300Ada08",
"XYZ33508H406Ada08"];
```

and

```
$b = ["XYZ0L200H150A4c00",
    "350L610H457Ada08",
    "XYZ33762H610Ada08",
    "350L914H610Ada08",
    "3700L250H200A410b",
    "XYZ33457H305Ada08",
    "XYZ4550H100MMQOJ",
    "XYZ4580H130Ada08",
    "XYZ4550H150A69b5",
    "3101L280H356A8b83",
    "XYZ4550H1501FC5Z",
    "3116L150H15074QFR",
    "XYZ1250H200A21ac",
    "3101L750H500A8b83",
    "350L356H279Ada08",
    "XYZ1250H200A3f1c",
    "3700L153H102A8d96",
    "XYZ4550H150Ada08",
    "XYZ4580H130A69b5",
    "350L1830H610Ada08",
    "3700L153H102A4c00",
    "XYZ4550H150STD9J",
    "3800L200H1505CZJI",
    "XYZ4550H100A69b5",
    "XYZ331370H450Ada08"
  ];
```

I need to see if values of array $a are there in array $b, I tried to use array_diff() and array_intersect() but that didn't solve the purpose. What I want is if the 2 arrays are matched then it should return either true or false. So for example if we consider value in $a -> "XYZ1280H130" and value in $b ->  "XYZ1280H130A69b5" then it should be considered as a matched value (coz former is a sub-string of latter value) and true should be return and same for all similar values.

I tried something like this but it gives back all values of array $b everytime:

```
$result = array_filter($a, function($item) use($b) {
  foreach($b as $substring)
    if(strpos($item, $substring) !== FALSE) return TRUE;
  return FALSE;
});
```

Please let me know if I missed something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add an example of the output you wanted this comparison to produce?

Comment: If all values of $a are there in $b then it should return true else if any value is missing from $b then false. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex:

```
foreach($b as $search){
      foreach($a as $sub){
       if(preg_match("/$sub/",$search)){ echo "found ".$sub." in ".$search;}
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way we can avoid double foreach loop coz am getting to this point of comparison already after couple of loops?

Comment: Not really because you need to run through each of the items in a, check against each item in b (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

You could use array_map.
But this should give you the result you want as well :

```
function test($a, $b) {
    foreach($a as $first) {
        foreach($b as $second) {
            if(strpos($b, $a) !== false) return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified one of the answers above by @clearshot66 to get the desired result:

```
function match_them($a, $b){    
    foreach($b as $search){
      foreach($a as $key => $val){
       if(preg_match("/$val/",$search)){unset($a[$key]);}
      }
    }   
    return count($a);
}
var_dump(match_them($a, $b));
```